# Copying a non-contiguous range in active sheet to select worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to:

1. Copy the numbers in the active sheet (TheRange)
2. Selectively target some sheets to paste the select range

```
Sub ProjectMonth()
    If MsgBox("This will project values in this month to all others! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    TheRange = "H3:H5,H9:H11,C6:D18,C22:D31,C35:D40,C44:D48,C52:D62,C66:D71,C75:D80,H20:I27,H31:I39,H43:I48,H52:I60,H64:I70,H75:I79"
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    ActiveSheet.Range(TheRange).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(TheRange).Copy
    For Each Sh In Sheets(Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
        With Sh.Range(TheRange)
                Selection.Paste
        End With
    Next
    MsgBox ("Sequence Complete!")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Let me know if any questions.

```
Sub PasteRanges()
    If MsgBox("This will project values in this month to all others! Are you sure?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Dim ranges As Variant, i As Integer, mainSheet As String, wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    mainSheet = "CopyFromSheet"
    ranges = Array("AH3:H5", "H9:H11", "C6:D18", "C22:D31", "C35:D40", "C44:D48", "C52:D62", "C66:D71", "C75:D80", "H20:I27", "H31:I39", "H43:I48", "H52:I60", "H64:I70", "H75:I79")
    For Each Sh In wb.Sheets(Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
        With Sh
            For i = 0 To UBound(ranges)
                wb.Sheets(mainSheet).Range(ranges(i)).Copy
                Sh.Range(ranges(i)).PasteSpecial xlValues
            Next i
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: If OP needs just values, you could get with `wb.Sheets(mainSheet).Range(ranges(i)) = Sh.Range(ranges(i))`

Comment: True, it would be cleaner and more correct with your suggestion. For now I will leave it as is since he mentioned he is not very good in VBA, this way he knows he can do more with the range if he wishes. With your suggestion it may confuse some that are not used to VBA but you are correct.